# Custom Annotation injecting property

Tags: java, annotations, spring-aop

I have a custom annotation LogExecution,  that i want to pass field values from a property file or java constants file (preferable) but for some reason this is not working, any help is appreciated.

```
@LogExecution(application = "${my.appname}",
      server= "${my.server.name}" )
  public void doSomething() {

  }
```

This still prints the values as literal ${my.appname} inside annotation code. LogExecution annotation is an aspect that uses @Around advice.

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? In which tutorial or manual did you read that you can do anything like this? Please edit the question and provide more information. BTW, if you are trying to use Spring Expression Language (SpEL), the syntax is different.

Comment: is there a tutorial available that explains how we can pass dynamic property values to an annotation? Question is, I am trying to pass these two attributes to my annotation from some properties available in application.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I will try to help you. The question as it is now contains insufficient information, I cannot answer it like this.